# Spring boot: inject a request-scoped, lazy-initialized custom User object into a controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm building a Spring Boot application to provide a stateless REST API. For security, we're using OAuth 2. My app receives a bearer-only token.

The user's information is stored in our database. I can look it up using the injected Principal in the controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(...)
public void endpoint(Principal p) {
  MyUser user = this.myUserRepository.findById(p.getName());
  ...
}
```

To avoid this extra line of boilerplate, I would like to be able to inject the MyUser object directly into my controller method. How can I achieve this? (The best I've come up with so far is to create a Lazy, Request-scoped @Bean...but I haven't been able to get it working...)

Answer (score 0):

#### The Idiomatic Way

The idiomatic way in Spring Security is to [use a `UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#userdetailsservice-implementations) or [implement your own](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-userdetailsservice):

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    MyUserRepository myUserRepository;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        return this.myUserRepository.findById(username);
    }
}
```

And then there are several spots in the Spring Security DSL where this can be deposited, depending on your needs.

Once integrated with the authentication method you are using (in this case OAuth 2.0), then you'd be able to do:

```
public void endpoint(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUser myuser) {

}
```

#### The Quick, but Less-Flexible Way

It's generally better to do this at authentication time (when the Principal is being ascertained) instead of at method-resolution time (using an argument resolver) as it makes it possible to use it in more authentication scenarios.

That said, you could also use the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` argument resolver with any bean that you have registered, e.g.

```
public void endpoint(
    @AuthenticationPrincipal(expression="@myBean.convert(#this)") MyUser user) 
{

}

...

@Bean
public Converter<Principal, MyUser> myBean() {
    return principal -> this.myUserRepository.findById(p.getName())
}
```

The tradeoff is that this conversion will be performed each time this method is invoked. Since your app is stateless, this might not be an issue (since the lookup needs to be performed on each request anyway), but it would mean that this controller could likely not be reused in other application profiles.

Comment: "there are several spots in the Spring Security DSL where this can be deposited" - could you list some of them? I think this is where I started getting lost...

Comment: For sure - can you tell me what version of Spring's oauth support you are using? For example, do you enable a resource server using `http.oauth2ResourceServer()` or using `@EnableResourceServer`? Spring Security recently did an overhaul of that support, so the answer is a little different depending on that.

Comment: I'm not sure...I'm using Keycloak and keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter version 4.0.0.Final, which contains keycloak-spring-security-adapter. This has a dependency on spring-security-config and spring-security-web version 3.2.7.RELEASE.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, that might be a bit more of a Keycloak question... but I see that the adapter ships with a KeycloakAuthenticationProvider. I would just quickly guess that extending that is what you'd want to do, and have that extension use your user details service.

Comment: Also, I realize you didn't ask this, but I wonder if your application really needs the entire user - could the OAuth token be updated to contain the user id so that you don't need to bother with looking up the user?

Comment: No, we're using Keycloak strictly for authentication/authorization. The regular user details (name, address, etc) are stored in the Application DB. (I know Keycloak can store these things but it's easier to keep them on the application side.) So the goal here is to (automatically) look up the user entity given the ID.

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to answer your question then, without altering your question. The answer, given the question, is correct. But, what you'd like is guidance on how to look up the user when using the keycloak-spring-boot-adapter. If it were me, I'd probably ask a new question - that way other users get helped too when they have a similar question.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but...it seems like this doesn't really have anything to do with Keycloak, specifically. Via [magic in Spring security], I have a Principal. I'd like to use this to automatically lookup and autowire an Entity (hopefully lazily, as not every endpoint will need it...and also with correct scope...).

What sorts of authentication scenarios are you talking about? Where would I need this, besides as an autowired method parameter?

Comment: The principal you are getting already in your method is what Spring Security produces. If you want your user to be a part of that principal, you need to inject yourself into the authentication process somehow; otherwise, how would Spring Security know what you want? Because you are using Keycloak's adapter, Keycloak enforces its opinion on how Spring Security ought to be wired (e.g., the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider). This means that you either need to articulate yourself within their API, bypass it, or somehow reset it after Keycloak is done. Maybe let's chat? Happy to keep helping.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by implementing HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.
For example:

Custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface Version {
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class HeaderVersionArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(Version.class) != null;
}

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(
  MethodParameter methodParameter, 
  ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer, 
  NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, 
  WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {

    HttpServletRequest request 
      = (HttpServletRequest) nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest();

    return request.getHeader("Version");
}
}
```

When you implement this you should add this as argument resolver:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(
  List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(new HeaderVersionArgumentResolver());
}
}
```

Now we can use it as argument

```
public ResponseEntity findByVersion(@PathVariable Long id, @Version String version)
```